# Is it possible to run a script on a register content and send its output to another register on Vim?

Tags: vimscript, register

Let's consider that I have the following bash script called `time.bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
date -d @$1
```

This script converts the epoch timestamp to its corresponding date as the following:

```
$ ./time.bash 1267619929
qua mar  3 09:38:49 -03 2010
```

Now let's suppose I'm editing the following file using Vim:

```
1267619929 word word 
1267619935 word word 
1267619931 word word 
1267619946 word word
```

Considering that I'm working just on a single line, I'd like to save the timestamp 1267619929 on the register `a` with `"aye`, execute the script `time.bash` with the register `a` content as input, and save its output on another register (let's say register `b`). Is it possible to do this kind of stuff on Vim?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this:

```
let @b=system("time.bash " . @a)
```

The `@a` is register `a` and `@b` is register `b`. The `system(...)` runs a command and returns the output. The result is a line, so when you paste it, you get a new line.

See `:help system()`.

Another way is:

```
call setreg("b", system("time.bash " . @a), "v")
```

Here you can set the mode for the register. The lower case `v` sets it to characterwise. With it you can paste the result within a line.

See `:help setreg()`

You could also do it without first copying the value to register `a`. Put the cursor on the numeric value and execute:

```
call setreg("b", system("time.bash " . expand("<cword>")), "v")
```

The `expand("<cword>")` is expanded to the word under the cursor.

See `:help <cword>` and `:help expand()`.

Comment: Thanks!! That was exactly what I needed... Now that I've played a little with these commands I've realized that without the `.` on `let @b=system("time.bash " . @a)` the command doesn't work. Just as a curiosity, what is the `.` purpose inside the `system` function?

Comment: @RafaelMuynarsk The dot is the operator for string concatenation.

Comment: Or (untested) `:s/<cword>/\=system("time.bash" . submatch(0)/`